# Merge two animations in plotly express (One with colorbar the other without)

Tags: animation, mapbox, plotly-express

Can I merge two animations in potly express, where one animation is attached to a colorbar and the other is not?

Like merging these two animations:

[image: Figure1]

[image: Figure2]

Answer (score -1):

So the answer to the question is to append frames of one animation in the other animation. This is the code I did to solve my problem

```
if len(Routes)==1:
    r_class=["Optimal Route"]

if len(Routes)==2:
  r_class=["Optimal Route","Alternative 1"]

if len(Routes)==3:
  r_class=["Optimal Route","Alternative 1","Alternative 2"]

df_routes, _, _ = Route2DataFrame(Routes, r_class, Routes_Node_AT, FloodNW,     start, end)
df_flood=CreateFloodDF(SavePlotFloodPath,TimeStep, StartTime, Routes_AT)
df_routes_criticalP=CreateRouteFloodLocationDF(df_flood, df_routes, r_class)


TimeFrames=np.unique(df_flood["Time"])
NumTimeFrames=len(TimeFrames)
NumberAltRoutes=len(Routes)


fig=px.scatter_mapbox(df_flood[df_flood["Y_from"]], lon= "X_from",         lat="Y_from",zoom=13, width=1000, height=800, color="Flood [mm]",     animation_frame="Time [s]", mapbox_style="dark", size_max=1e-9, opacity=0.1)
fig2=px.scatter_mapbox(df_routes_criticalP, lon= "X_from", lat="Y_from", color="Class",animation_frame="Time [s]", size="Size", mapbox_style="dark",zoom=13, width=1000, height=800)


for i in range(NumberAltRoutes):
  fig.add_trace(fig2.data[i])
  for k in range(TimeFrames):
    fig.frames[k].data += (fig2.frames[k].data[i],)

for i in range(NumberAltRoutes):
  fig.add_traces(px.line_mapbox(df_routes, lon= "X_from", lat="Y_from",     color="Class").data[i])


fig.layout.coloraxis.colorbar.title.update(font = dict(size = 14))
fig.update_layout(legend = dict(font = dict(size = 14)))
fig.update_traces(line=dict(width=5))

fig.layout.coloraxis.colorbar.x=-0.14
fig.layout.coloraxis.cmax=300
fig.layout.coloraxis.cmin=0

fig.write_html(DataDirectory+"/OptimalRoute.html")
fig.show()
```